# Mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, jquery, html

Não, estou a perceber o porque de me estar com esse erro, visto que apenas quero fazer um simples update, e tenho o parametro necessário no fetch

> ERRO : Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, object given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto2\Aluno\AlterarAluno.php on line 17

```
 <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proj");
        echo $email=$_POST['email'];

        $inst0="Select Email from utilizador ";
        $result0=mysqli_query($conn,$inst0);
        echo $numlinhas1=mysqli_num_rows($result0);
        //echo $numlinhas1;
        //echo var_dump($_POST);
        if ($numlinhas1 > 0)
        {

            $inst3="Update utilizador set Email = '".$email."'";
            echo "xxx";
            $result0=mysqli_query($conn,$inst3);
            $result1=mysqli_fetch_row($conn);

            $_SESSION['mensagem'] ="Dado atualizado";
             //header("Location:IndexAluno.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: qual o erro exibido?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto2\Aluno\AlterarAluno.php on line 17

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em um `UPDATE`, nenhum valor é retornado, tal como seria em um `SELECT`. Logo, não é necessário utilizar a função `mysqli_fetch_row()` para saber se a operação ocorreceu com sucesso ou não com um `if`.

Para saber o número de linhas afetadas por um `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, use a função [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Outro detalhe **importante**: seu `UPDATE` não possui uma clásula `WHERE` ou seja todas as linhas dessa tabela serão alteradas com o mesmo valor na coluna `email`.

Mude:

```
$result0=mysqli_query($conn,$inst3);
$result1=mysqli_fetch_row($conn);
```

Para:

```
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $inst3)){ 
   echo 'erro: '. mysqli_error($conn);
}else{
   echo 'linhas alteradas: '. mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
}
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5ccdd6388ae48febb50e4aed23e0951c :(

Comment: @Paulo não consigo abrir essa imagem, qual erro aparece?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string

Comment: @Paulo corrigido, eu deveria ter passado a string do update, por engano passei a variável errada, veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: valeeu ! corrigiu o meu problema !

Comment: @Paulo **cuidado com update SEM WHERE**

Comment: Okey ! vou passar a estar mais atento

Answer (score 3):

Existem dois erros:

**1. Variável `$conn`:**

O `mysqli_fetch_row()` espera o resultado do `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` ou `mysqli_use_result()`, [veja aqui na documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), e não o `mysqli_connect()`.

Basicamente:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(....);

$query = mysqli_query($con, ...);

$fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

No seu caso está usando:

```
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($con);
```

Este é o erro, pois a variavel `$con` não é um `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` ou `mysqli_use_result()`, mas um `mysqli_connect()`, o que não é suportada pela função.

**2. Fetch em UPDATE:**

O `mysqli_fetch_row` apenas funciona em SELECT, você deve usar em seu lugar o `mysqli_affected_rows`, que é o mais próximo que pode fazer. Ele irá obter o número de linhas afetadas, mas não o seu conteúdo. Esta função suporta `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` ou `DELETE`, mas não suporta `SELECT`.

Comment: eu usava sempre a conneção, muita falta de atenção

Answer (score 3):

No exemplo abaixo coloquei a cláusula `WHERE id = 1`, você deve colocar a cláusula `WHERE` de acordo com sua necessidade, se não colocar, irá alterar todos os registros.

Código:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

    $conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proj");
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $inst0 = "SELECT Email FROM utilizador WHERE id = 1";
    $result0 = mysqli_query($conn, $inst0);
    $numlinhas1 = mysqli_num_rows($result0);
    //echo $numlinhas1;
    //echo var_dump($_POST);

    if ($numlinhas1 > 0)
    {
        $inst3 = "UPDATE utilizador SET Email = '".$email."' WHERE id=1";

        if($result0 = mysqli_query($conn, $inst3))
        {
            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Dado atualizado";
            //header("Location:IndexAluno.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

O método `mysqli_fetch_row()` recebe um resultado de query, no seu caso vc está inserindo uma conexão.

Acho que o que você precisa é passar o `$result0` no método `mysqli_fetch_row()`.

ficaria assim:

```
$result1=mysqli_fetch_row($result0);
```

[Mais informações sobre o método mysqli_fetch_row()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Comment: O erro mantem-se infelizmente, nunca tive tanta dificuldade fazendo um update

Comment: Faz o seguinte adiciona isso e posta aqui, abaixo de $result0:
dd($result0);

Comment: já consegui resolver, obrigado Jedson :D